# Ignore records in FirebaseDB with swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on a swift app that displays records from firebase to a table view controller.

I have successfully been pulling in all data, But I have since added another field to the DB called "secretKey".. This doesn't not need to be used on the table view as its used elsewhere in the app

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENAyM.png]

But now each time I try to run the app I get the following errors

```
2018-05-07 12:24:24.616490+0100 Loop Guardian[21847:9857567] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSTaggedPointerString 0xa030818c015ea1f9> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key createdAt.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18204b164 0x181294528 0x18204ae2c 0x1829fe434 0x182944e20 0x182944874 0x18297d930 0x1030084b0 0x103008740 0x1030f2840 0x1044892cc 0x10448928c 0x10448dea0 0x181ff3344 0x181ff0f20 0x181f10c58 0x183dbcf84 0x18b6695c4 0x10301de44 0x181a3056c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This only happens when the secretKey is present in the DB.. If I remove it the app works fine.

I somehow need to ignore this field

Heres the code used to pull the records from the DB

```
func observeMessages() {
    let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String
    DBrefs.databaseMessages.child(key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                self.dataArr = []
                for (key,data) in messageData {
                    self.dataArr.append(data)
                }
                //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN.. THREAD 1: SIGNAL SIGABRT
                self.dataArr = (self.dataArr as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)]) as [AnyObject]
                self.tblMessage.reloadData()
            }
            else {
            }
        })
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (key,data) in messageData { 
    if (key == "secreyKey") {
       continue;
    }
    self.dataArr.append(data)
}
```

Also use `Swift` method to sort the `Array`. Don't use `NSArray` use `Array` instead.

Like below code:

```
self.dataArr.sorted(by: {$0["createdAt"] as? Int64 ?? 0 < $1["createdAt"] as? Int64 ?? 0})
```